# What is a way to sculpt/model clothes that aren't stuck to the body?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

So I know how to sculpt tight clothes onto the body (plane > merge at center >modifiers like shrinkwrap > make verteces) and I know how to make wider clothes that are stuck on the body (sculpt them and then retopologize).

But how do I make thinks like e.g. capes or hoods? Or what's the method called so I can search it up? :)

Comment: you could use cloth physics at the beginning then apply?

Comment: I think that would look too real maybe, I wanna go for a stylized look

Comment: if you keep the mesh low-poly it won't look realistic

Comment: Do you think it would work if I made the shape with verteces but don't use shrinkwrap like I would with tight clothing? I don't even know how to attach clothes to a body without actually merging it (or do I not have to)? :(

Comment: are you planning to animate? Maybe show a picture of the kind of cape you want to create, it will help, you could simply create a simple shape then give a bit of folding in Edit or Sculpt mode?

Comment: Your answer was helpful! I didn't know you could just sculpt on top! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give some details about the style of cape, if it is supposed to be animated, etc... There are several approaches, like modeling it, sculpting it, or using cloth simulation.

You can **sculpt** it:

- Prepare a vertical plane, subdivide it a bit:

[image]

- Use brushes like the *Draw* brush to dig or bump the shape (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to dig, you can also try the *Crease* brush for more sharp details):

[image]

- You can also use the Grab brush to deform the shape. There should be even more convenient brushes in next Blender that will easily allow to bend the mesh:

[image]

Or you can begin with a **Cloth** simulation:

- Create a plane, give it a group at its top edge. Give it a *Cloth* physics, with for example the silk settings, in the *Physics* panel > *Shape* choose the group as the *Pin Group*. Select the body (here a simple cylinder) and give it a *Physics > Collision*:

[image]

- Play the animation. Stop it when you're glad with the result, and in the modifiers, apply the *Cloth*. Now you can edit it the way you want.

[image]